# how to make NULL values in UPDATE to leave column unmodified

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I want to update data in a SQLite table from a Node.js Application.

Suppose I have a "things" table with 3 columns: "id","code" and "name".

So, I create a express PUT route where I build an UPDATE SQL statement with some variables extracted from the parsed body.

```
app.put("/:id",function (req, res, next) {
  db.run("UPDATE things SET code=?, name=? WHERE id=?",
     [req.body.code,req.body.name,req.params.id],
     function(err) {
       ...
  })
}
```

I can update my table with the put verb

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --request PUT \
     --data '{"code":"ALC","name":"Alice"}' \
     http://localhost:3000/1
```

so far, so good.

But, in certain scenarios, I just want to update one column of the row, leaving all other columns unmodified. I want my user to be able to invoke my interface by just

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --request PUT \
     --data '{"name":"Anna"}' \
     http://localhost:3000/1
```

however, the result of this operation sets the "code" column to NULL, instead of leaving it unmodified.

Is it possible to write an UPDATE statement that can make this result? or do I need to dynamically build different UPDATE statements?

In the example, there would be three depending if I want to modify one, another or both columns? but it will become very inconvenient in a real world scenario with more than 20 possible update columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `COALESCE` function to set a column to its current value if the parameter provided for that column is `NULL`. This is ISO SQL standard stuff except the names of parameters. I don't know what RDBMS you're using, but I assume it supports named parameters (all modern RDBMS databases support named parameters, but using their own different syntax)

```
UPDATE
    foo
SET
    Col1 = COALESCE( @param1, Col1 ),
    Col2 = COALESCE( @param2, Col2 ),
    Col3 = COALESCE( @param3, Col3 )
WHERE
    PrimaryKeyCol = @primaryKey
```